# I cannot submit a form neither using .click() nor using .submit()

Tags: javascript, html, puppeteer

In an external webpage that I do not administrate, I have to fill a form that has no id or name. The "submit" button code looks like this:

```
<button type="submit" class="sui-AtomButton sui-AtomButton--primary sui-AtomButton--solid sui-AtomButton--center">
  <span class="sui-AtomButton-inner">Save</span></button>
```

At first I tried a simple click like this:

```
await.page.click('[type="submit"]')
```

The button was clicked but it did not trigger the submition of the form (I also tried using "Enter" with the keyboard, but the result is the same).

Then, I tried to trigger the submit from the own form like this:

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
      
 document.forms[0].submit();

})
```

and like this:

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
 
 var f = document.forms[0]
 Object.getPrototypeOf(f).submit.call(f);

})
```

and also like this:

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
      
 document.forms[0].submit(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
 });

})
```

In all the three cases the result is an error in the page.

What should I do?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What framework are you using to drive the page?

Comment: @DaveNewton It is not a web page that I am creating or managing. I use my script (with puppeteer+chromium) to fill a form of an external web page.

Comment: You may have to check for the presence of the button (e.g., it may be added dynamically) or existing click handlers that change the default click functionality.

Comment: Why are you passing a function in the submit method?

Comment: Wait for it and click it? `await page.waitForSelector('button[type="submit"]');
await page.click('button[type="submit"]');`

Comment: @epascarello I also tried with ```page.waitForSelector('button[type="submit"]')``` before the click but it doesn't work

Comment: Hard to guess why it does not work without seeing the code of the site. Look at the form, see what they are doing to listen to the submit. Look at the button. Figure out what they are doing.

Comment: @DaveNewton the button is there statically, but I guess they introduced a function to prevent submition depending on the "behavior" of the user: If it is not a normal behavior the code of the web page disable the submition. Actually, I am not a professional, but I think this could be the problem after checking the hidden code of their webpage, and I do not know what to do...

Answer (score 1):

See that in your JS code you don't have this:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

if you have this code then it will prevent the form to be submitted.